# Load script only if window is larger than X

Tags: javascript, responsive-design

I am currently using the script below, but noticed that it only works with screen size, not window size, so resizing the browser does not trigger it. How can I get this to run only when the screen size is larger than X? Are there any consideration that I should take into account for retina displays?

```
<script>
if (screen && screen.width > 899) {
document.write('<script async type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/myscript.js"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be accomplished with `window.matchMedia` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia))

```
<script>
  var mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 400px)');

  mediaQuery.addListener(loadScripts);

  function loadScripts() {
    document.write('\x3Cscript src="myScript.js">\x3C/script>');
  }    
</script>

<script src="mySecondScript.js"></script>
<script src="myThirdScript.js"></script>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/yr3wb9f3/).

Comment: although it won't trigger on resize only on refresh (if viewing on desktop)

Comment: Thank you for your help @BrettDeWoody This seems to affect all scripts. How do I modify this so that it only affects one specific script? i.e. "myscript.js"?

Comment: You would only add the scripts you want to load within the `loadScripts()` function. I updated the answer to show how other scripts would be loaded as normal independent of `window.matchMedia`.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `screen` go with `window`:

```js
var out = document.getElementById('out');
var foo = function() {
  console.log('resized ...');
  if (window.innerWidth > 899) {
    alert('load script');
  }
  out.innerHTML = window.innerWidth;
};

window.onresize = foo; // run code on window resize

foo(); //run code on page load
```

```html
Resize window, width: <span id="out"></span>px
```